# How to fix index error when separating csv files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given an input CSV file:

```
Sample A B C D
Sample_1 0 1 0 0
Sample_2 1 0 0 0
Sample_3 0 0 1 0
Sample_4 0 0 0 1
Sample_5 1 0 0 0
Sample_6 0 1 0 0
```

I would like to sort the samples into a control, experimental, and neither list. All the samples with a "1" in the A column will be placed in the control list, all samples with a "1" in B will be placed in the experimental list, and all sampled with a "1" in C or D will be placed in the neither list. Here is the desired output:

```
Control: sample_2, sample_5
Experimental: sample_1, sample_6
Neither: sample_3, sample_4
```

However I am getting this error message "IndexError: string index out of range on the line" on the line "if row[1] == "1":"

```
control = []
experimental = []
neither = []

filename = "filename.csv"

infile = open(filename, 'r') 
lines = infile.readlines() 

for line in lines:
    sline = line.split(',')  
    #print(sline) 
for row in sline:
  if row[1] == "1":
    control.append(row[0])
  elif row[2] == "1":
      experimental.append(row[0])
  else:
      neither.append(row[0])
  print(length(control))
  print(length(experimental))
  print(length(neither))

infile.close()
```

Comment: Does your csv have empty lines between rows or was this just an atrifact of posting here?

Comment: No the CSV doesn't have empty spaces between rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your error is in the for loop. Is not well formatted, also is possible that you are having some empty lines and therefore we could omit them. Like this:

```py
for line in lines:
    sline = line.split() # The split character is white spaces not comma
    if len(sline) == 5:
        seq,a,b,c,d = sline
        if "1" in a:
            control.append(seq)
        elif "1" in b:
            experimental.append(seq)
        else:
            neither.append(seq)

# Print results
print(length(control))
print(length(experimental))
print(length(neither))

infile.close()
```

This approach assumes that the lines that you have interest in always contain five pieces of information.

Let me know if this worked for you! :D

Comment: Thank you! However I am outputting empty lists, so I don't think anything is being appended.

Comment: It actually worked for me, I test with the data that you included in your post. Are you sure that your data is separated by spaces?

Comment: Thank you! I just checked and it worked, my data is separated by commas!

Comment: Glad that it helped! Good Luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that

```
for line in lines:
    sline = line.split(',')  
    #print(sline)
```

doesn't update anything and the split lines are simply discarded.

You can use the csv module to do the splitting (and use 4 space indents consistently) as in

```
import csv

control = []
experimental = []
neither = []

filename = "filename.csv"

try:
    with open(filename, newline='') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ')
        # dispose of header
        next(reader)
        for index, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
            if row[1] == "1":
                control.append(row[0])
            elif row[2] == "1":
                experimental.append(row[0])
            else:
                neither.append(row[0])
except IndexError:
    print("Invalid row {} in {}. Missing columns: {}".format(index, filename, row))
print(len(control))
print(len(experimental))
print(len(neither))
```

Comment: I have the same error message "IndexError: list index out of range" for the line "if row[1] == "1":"

Comment: @elly_jelly - it worked for the sample provided. You could add a print(row) above the test and see which row gives you a problem. It appears that a row in your sample data only has 1 column.

Comment: print(row) only outputs the first row, is it supposed to output each row?

Comment: @elly_jelly - It depends on where the print is. I updated the example to catch the index error and print the guilty party.